# How to add slide in the middle of presentation using python-pptx?

Tags: apache-poi, python-pptx

I have a template.pptx , having 10 slides in total. I want to copy a slide/layout of slide 2 and add new slide after 2, between 2 and 3.

what I can do currently is copy and add the slide at the end of presentation.

```
prs = Presentation('C:\Documents\template.pptx')
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[1])
prs.save('C:\Documents\template_save.pptx')
```

Can I do this using java apache-poi?

Comment: Inserting a slide (into the middle) is currently not possible with POI. The simple approach would be to copy the slides/layouts/master to a new slideshow, which also has some drawbacks. I can't promise you something timely, but you can always open a bugzilla entry and I'll try to implement it ... if using POI is an option for you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the hybrid approach and it works well.

1. Copy and add slide at the end of presentation with python-pptx
2. Reorder slides with Apache POI

`ppt.setSlideOrder(slides.length-1, 4); // Bring last slide to 5th position`

Comment: so you open the pres with python-pptx do some work then save it, then open it again but this time with Apachie POI and do some work and save it again?

Answer (score 1):

```
from pptx import Presentation
def move_slide(old_index, new_index):
    xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst
    slides = list(xml_slides)
    xml_slides.remove(slides[old_index])
    xml_slides.insert(new_index, slides[old_index])
presentation = Presentation(pptpath)
layout = presentation.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[6]
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(layout)
slide_id = presentation.slides.index(slide)
move_slide(slide_id, 3)
presentation.save(pptpath)
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer,