# How to paste text into following slides in a powerpoint document via python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am using Python PPTX library to paste some text into a powerpoint slide. As you can see from the code below, it takes the text stored in the text_into_slide variable and pastes into a specific slide which has a title of `Advantages`. The text includes some points. When there are 5-6 points I have no problem. But I usually have ca 15 points. What I want this code to do is: paste the first 5 points into the slide with the `Advantages` title. If there are more than 5 points, then create a new slide for each new 5 points and paste them into these slides. Actually it does this. But the problem is it creates the new slides not immediately after the slide with the `Advantages` title but rather at the end of the document. More clearly, let's say the `Advantages` slide is the 8th slide and I want the code to paste the remaining 5 point chunks to subsequent slides such  as 9th, 10th slide etc. But if there are 15 slides in total, it pastes the remaining points as 16th, 17th slide in the end. Can someone help me to edit the code to paste remaining points immediately after the slide with `Advantages` title? Thanks in advance

PS: `Advantages` slide is not always the 8th one. It depends on the project, sometimes 6th, sometimes 10th...

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Pt
from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN

# Load the PowerPoint presentation
pptx_file = "23102023_Presentation.pptx"
presentation = Presentation(pptx_file)

# Search for the slide titled "Advantages"
target_slide_title = "Advantages"
found_slide = None

for i, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
    if slide.shapes.title.text == target_slide_title:
        found_slide = slide
        found_slide_index = i
        break

# Check if the slide was found
if found_slide is not None:
    # Define the text to insert
    text_into_slide_text = text_into_slide.replace("\n\n", "\n").split('\n')  # Split the text into individual points

    # Find the content placeholder in the slide
    content_placeholder = None
    for placeholder in found_slide.placeholders:
        if placeholder.placeholder_format.idx == 1:  
            content_placeholder = placeholder
            break

    if content_placeholder:
        text_frame = content_placeholder.text_frame

        # Split the text into chunks of 5 points each
        chunk_size = 5
        chunks = [text_into_slide_text[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(text_into_slide_text), chunk_size)]

        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            if i > 0:
                # Create a new slide using the same layout
                new_slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(found_slide.slide_layout)

                # Find the content placeholder in the new slide
                new_content_placeholder = None
                for placeholder in new_slide.placeholders:
                    if placeholder.placeholder_format.idx == 1:
                        new_content_placeholder = placeholder
                        break

            # Use the content placeholder from the first slide for the first chunk
            current_content_placeholder = content_placeholder if i == 0 else new_content_placeholder

            text_frame = current_content_placeholder.text_frame

            # Set the font size and style for the new text
            for point in chunk:
                p = text_frame.add_paragraph()
                run = p.add_run()
                run.text = point
                font = run.font
                font.size = Pt(9)  # Set font size to 9pt
                font.name = "Arial"  # Set font to Arial

        # Reorder the slides to place the new slide immediately after the found slide
        presentation.slides._sldIdLst.insert(found_slide_index + 1, new_slide._element)

        # Save the modified presentation
        presentation.save("23102023_Presentation.pptx")
        print("Text added to the 'Advantages' slide and subsequent slides.")
    else:
        print("Content placeholder not found on the 'Advantages' slide.")
else:
    print("Slide not found.")
```

Comment: As you have found the target slide, you can tweak the function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74797905/18571565) to move the new slides.

Comment: I already did but it did not work. I added something like to the code above:

`def move_slide(old_index, new_index):`
    `xml_slides = presentation.slides._sldIdLst`
    `slides = list(xml_slides)`
    `xml_slides.remove(slides[old_index])`
    `xml_slides.insert(new_index, slides[old_index])`

and then :

`move_slide(found_slide_index + 1, found_slide_index + 2)`

I don't know what's the problem!

Comment: When slides are added, as you mentioned these are always appended to the end.  So the "old index" value should be the last slide index value (something like presentation.slides.count I think) and then the new index would be "found slide index" + 1 or 2 for the relevent slide.  It looks like above you are swapping the slide directly after the found slide (Advantages) with the slide after.